# Reverse proxy to an external api from Google Cloud Load balancer

Tags: google-cloud-platform, reverse-proxy, google-cloud-load-balancer

I have set up Cloud Storage, Cloud DNS, and Load Balancing and I am able to access my site from the cloud DNS domain/subdomain I have set up through the load balancer.

In my dev website, I am able to reverse proxy `/api` to another server, I want to achieve similar results in GCP. The service/server I am reverse proxying to is not hosted in GCP.

Is it possible to do it? If yes how?

Answer (score 4):

The service/server you want to reverse proxy to is accessible on the internet ?

If yes you can use Internet Endpoint Group with Google Cloud load balancers.

https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/negs/internet-neg-concepts